# Blazorise using bootstrap Display Property

Tags: c#, bootstrap-4, blazorise

In bootstrap I can do something like `<div class="d-none d-sm-block"></div>` to hide on XS devices.

I do not see a wrapper for this in `Blazorise`.  Is there a known syntax/wrapper to do same thing in `Blazorise`?  If not I can obviously just do it with a `class` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Display property will officially be available in v0.9.1. In the meantime if you're willing to try one of preview versions, you can already use it. https://github.com/stsrki/Blazorise#try-preview

Comment: thanks! i'll try switching to preview for now since this app is just in development at this point.